# Need help in a batch file script for chatbot

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, chatbot

Hi I'm newbie need help create chatbot in bat script.

Can you help me some idea to add more script to make this better chatbot because I'm lack of knowledge about bat script.

**example:** I want chat result stored in `conversations.txt` those results used to be a basic knowledge of the chatbot to answer questions next time conversations.

Can anyone help me to add more script on

This is that script :

```bat
@echo off
title STILL BLACK chatbot

:early
color 1b

:start
echo hi, how are you ??!
set /p how=
echo oh %how% doing the same with me!
pause
echo My Name STILL BLACK !!! Who's your name ?
set /p name=
echo Nice to meet you echo %name%!
pause
echo how old are you %name% ?
set /p age=
echo hmmm ... %age% !
pause
echo where do you live ?
set /p live=
echo exactly where is %live% that place?
set /p exactly=
echo wow %exactly% I rather not be there?!?
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the conversion to a file by using `>>` on your `echo`'s

```
echo oh %how% doing the same with me! >>conversation.txt
```

Other than that, you need to provide a **LOT** more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks for help can you more specific with LOT ?!? please give me some tips example LOT that i must to do, thanks ;)

Comment: I just meant your question was very vague, you need to give details on specific things you want to do :)

Comment: I hope you can give me tips for making brain of chatbot, mybe someday this useful for more interactive conversion in chatbot xixixixi ;) I saw your profile wow your master in bat, like that !

Comment: I would suggest you put your questions in a text file and then ask each of them using a [for loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), that will make your code a lot cleaner, then you could maybe use [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to pick out key words from the answers and find the appropriate responses in a answer text file :)

Comment: No worries :) Have a go at some of those commands, and if you get stuck post what you are having trouble with here as a new question. You can also accept an answer if it answered your question by clicking the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to make a "chatbot" like this, but of course it isn't fun writing to him. It's much better taking all answers and questions in a txt file in this style:

```
user input:output
other user input:other output
```

with for /f and findstr you can search after a code in your txt
and show the correct answer

the user input can be saved in an txt file by using

```
%input%>>conversations.txt
```

or you write it in the database eg

```
age:42
live:Germany
```

(doing with:`%art%:%wert%>>database.dat`)

sorry for this very late answer but saw this here today and wanted to answer it completely, when you have questions please let me know

greetings, Tim